# Is there a way to condition output on a given date?

Tags: pattern

I'd like to be able to print text that varies depending on whether the date matches a given date string

For example  suppose there was a command

```
\iftoday#1#2#3
```

which printed `#2` if `\today` matched the string in `#1` and `#3` otherwise.

So a sample of my proposed usage would be:

```
   \iftoday{February 3, 2016}{There's no garbage today}{Please put out the garbage}
```

I've tried various commands like pdftexcmd's strcmp, to no avail.

I suspect the problem may have to do with matching the string generated by `\today`.    While on screen it appears that `\today` returns `February 3, 2016`. I can't get it to match `February 3, 2016` when I compare strings.

Obviously, I'd be perfectly happy if I could get this to work by represent today's date in any of the standard date formats.

Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: `\today`is already fairly complex; from `texdef`: `\today:
macro:->\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi \space \number \day , \number \year`. You might have better luck with `pgfcalendar`'s `\pgfcalendarifdate{ date }{ tests }{ code }{ else code }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will allow the day, month and year to be specified *numerically* then this is fairly straightforward. The trick is that TeX also defines integers `\day`, `\month` and `\year` so you can compare these with the supplied date using `\ifnum`. This allows you to produce:

[image]

using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
% \ifToday{day}{month}{year}{yes message}{no message}
% for numerical day, month and year
\newif\iftoday
\newcommand\ifToday[5]{\todayfalse% it's not today by default!
    \ifnum\day=#1\relax\ifnum\month=#2\relax\ifnum\year=#3\relax\todaytrue\fi\fi\fi%
    \iftoday#4\else#5\fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \ifToday{3}{2}{2016}{There's no garbage today}{Please put out the garbage today}

    \ifToday{4}{2}{2016}{There's no garbage tomorrow}{Please put out the garbage tomorrow}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I tried some of the other solutions but they conflicted with one of my default packages, can't figure out which one.    but this one doesn't.       If anybody's using it in the US, you would want to reverse day and month in the \ifnum line.

Comment: LeoSimon -- The conflict is surprising. With mine it is possible; surprising, but possible. However, for there to be a conflict with @werner's solution is downright incredible (in the literal sense of the word).

Answer (score 4):

A PGF answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}
\newcommand\iftoday[1]{%
\pgfcalendarifdate{#1}{equals=\year-\month-\day}{There's no garbage today}{Please put out the garbage}}
\begin{document}

You know what to do:
\iftoday{2016-02-02}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @jon.   More generally, is it possible to extend your  pgf answer  to condition on a range of months or years?    To be concrete, I'd like to be able to display the answer to a question in my lecture notes, but only after this years problem set has been handed in, but before next year's class has started.    Say for example, between 4/18/2016 and 1/1/2017?   Thanks for your help.   I'll use any date format that works.

Comment: @LeoSimon -- Do you mean: if the date falls between range X and Y, then print A; otherwise print B?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.   Sorry for not being more explicit

Answer (score 2):

This does depend on your date format:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iftoday}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\today}{#1}=0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\today

\iftoday{February 2, 2016}
  {There's no garbage today}% <true>
  {Please put out the garbage}% <false>

\iftoday{February 3, 2016}
  {There's no garbage today}% <true>
  {Please put out the garbage}% <false>

\end{document}
```